# Odd ratio become different direction after adding other variables in logistic regression model

Tags: regression, logistic, spss, odds-ratio

I am doing a logistic regression to test out the relationship between problematic behaviour and a number of variables e.g. self-centeredness, delinquent peers, childhood adversity and parenting.

If I put "self-centeredness" alone into the model, it is

[image]

But then, if I added other variables altogether, it becomes
[image]

My question is, how should I interpret the change of direction of the odds ratio (from 1.045>1, to 0.879 <1). Can it be explained by any statistical phenomenon? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a case of Omitted Variable Bias.

In the first model, you are including only self-centeredness as the independent variable. This means that you are excluding/omitting some important independent variables from the model. If any of the omitted variables are correlated with self-centeredness, the model will end up attributing the effects of those omitted variables to self-centeredness. So, your coefficient will actually represent the effects of self-centeredness as well as the effects of those correlated omitted variables.

You can observe that in the second model where parenting, childhood adversity and delinquent peers are significantly affecting your dependent variable. When these variables were included, the coefficient of self-centeredness changes its sign because the effects of these variables may have been removed from the coefficient.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply!
So if that's the case, should I still consider "Self-centeredness" as a significant predictor with a positive direction or i should have ignored it as it seems to be the least predictive factors with a negative direction.

Comment: So can I still consider "self-centeredness" as a significant predictor?

Comment: You should check for any multicollinearity in the second regression with all the variables. If there is no multicollinearity, you can say that self-centeredness is negatively affecting your dependent variable. The coefficient is significant. This seems to be the opposite of what you expect, could be due to multicollinearity. The first regression results are biased, so you should not make any inference from that.

Comment: besides omitted variable bias, can it be explained by moderating effect?

Comment: @winkie you can try including interaction variables in your regression. It might give you more information about this. If there are no significant interactions between variables, you can rule out moderating effect.