# Logistics regression gives opposite result than 2 by 2 table

Tags: regression, logistic

I am running logistic regression on sas. My outcome var is if student retained or not. One of my independent variable, if they attended first year oritentation is showing opposite result than what is should be.

Here is 2 by 2 table. upper columns indicate if they attended orientaion(1) or not attended(0). row columns indicate if they retained(1) or did not retained(0).
As you can see, if they attended orientation they are more likey to be retained compared to those who did not attended orientaion.

[image]

However, when I run logistics regression, it gives me opposite result.
It shows when they did not attend orientation, they are more likey to be retained...
Why is this happening? I have no idea what is going on. Please help me how to understand this situation or how I can fix this issue....

Thus, sadly I am not very familier with mathmatical vocabulary, so please be easy on explanation. Thank you a lot!!

[image]

Comment: And what does logistic regression show when you use only  `ORguest` and no other variables as the predictor?

Comment: In addition to Igor F.'s comment, this other question should interest you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/582473/odd-ratio-become-different-direction-after-adding-other-variables-in-logistic-re

Comment: Why do you expect the same result ? These are different models. The second one adjusts for several other variables. It's possible that the association between `ORguest` and the outcome in the chi-squared test is confounded, and that one or more covariates in 2nd model adjust for that.